# NSDistributedNotificationCenter not working

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

I'm implementing a VPN app (Packet Tunnel Provider).

I have a "containing" app, and an extension.
 Both app are in sandbox mode.
I want to use NSDistributedNotificationCenter and send a message from the extension to the containing app, but it's not working.

Here is the code at the extension:

```
let distributedNotificationCenter = NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
distributedNotificationCenter.postNotificationName("myNotification", object: nil, userInfo: nil, deliverImmediately: true)
```

And this is at the containing app:

```
let distributedNotificationCenter = NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
distributedNotificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CNConnectViewController.doNotification(_:)), name: "myNotification", object: nil)

func doNotification(message: NSNotification) {
     NSLog("doNotification")
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, in order this to work one need to use an object name because of the sandbox

Answer (score 2):

Sending user-info dictionaries in broadcast notifications to other tasks. With App Sandbox, you cannot include a user-info dictionary when posting to an NSDistributedNotificationCenter object for messaging other tasks.